# How to use ALTER TABLE in MySQL on a column named partition

Tags: mysql, reserved-words

I have a MySQL table with a column named partition. As it's a reserved keyword, I should be able to use `backticks` to use it in queries. It works with `SELECT`, but not with `ALTER TABLE`.

If I try :

```
ALTER TABLE `table` DROP `partition`;
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE `table` CHANGE `partition` `othername` INT;
```

MySQL complains with the same error :

```
Error code 1054: Unknown column 'partition' in 'partition function'
```

I tried in 'terminal', via MySQL Workbench or through Java `JDBC`, I always get the same error.

Any suggestion to get rid of that column (without losing / re-creating the whole table ...) ?

EDIT:
You can test it with a small table like that :

```
CREATE TABLE `testpart` (`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `partition` smallint(6) NOT NULL, UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`,`partition`)) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 PARTITION BY HASH(partition) PARTITIONS 16;
```

Then try

```
ALTER TABLE `testpart` DROP COLUMN `partition`;
```

Comment: Sounds like something to report at http:bugs.mysql.com .

Comment: There is probably no benefit from `PARTITION BY HASH`, so I suggest simply getting rid of partitioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first try is nearly correct, but you must say what to drop **COLUMN**. try this to delete them. Backticks are also working.

```
ALTER TABLE `table` DROP COLUMN `partition`;
```

here is the Manual page from Mariadb : https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/alter-table/

**sample**

i must add some infos to my answer:

- the table has PARTITION
- and the COLUMN that you want to change / remove is the KEY therefore
- you must first remove the PARTITION before you can change them
- the name of the COLUMN is a KEYWORD, so you must always quote it with backticks

**create a table with 16 partitions**

```
MariaDB [yourschema]> CREATE TABLE testpart (
    ->   id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   `PARTITION` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL,
    ->   UNIQUE KEY id (id,`PARTITION`)
    -> ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
    -> PARTITION BY HASH (`PARTITION`)
    -> PARTITIONS 16 ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.12 sec)
```

**now remove the paritions**

```
MariaDB [yourschema]> ALTER TABLE `testpart` REMOVE PARTITIONING;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.35 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

**remove the (or change) the COLUMN**

```
MariaDB [yourschema]> ALTER TABLE `testpart` DROP COLUMN `PARTITION`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.21 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [yourschema]>
```

Comment: The COLUMN keyword is not mandatory, but I've already tried with it, and no difference.

Comment: please post the output from : **SHOW CREATE TABLE `yourTable`;**

Comment: CREATE TABLE `testpart` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `partition` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`,`partition`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
/*!50100 PARTITION BY HASH (partition)
PARTITIONS 16 */

Comment: Ok, you Must Remote the partitioning from the Tablet before you van Remote this Field i will ask later ist Hard from my phone

Comment: Yes I realize that after writing your example. If I start by ALTER TABLE testpart REMOVE PARTITIONING; it works fine ! Thank you !

Comment: @Raphaël - i have add a sample for you in my answer. let me know if it not works for you

Answer (score 0):

Does partition column have int values?
Try changing that accordly.

Comment: Yes it has INT values. I've tried

    ALTER TABLE `table` CHANGE `partition` `othername` DOUBLE;

same error